# xcode crashes with Assertion Failure at launch

Tags: xcode

Right in the middle of working in Xcode, when adding a simulator to it, it crashed. When I reopen Xcode, it crashes again but gives opportunity to send error report to apple. In the window I can read:

**ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-11515/IDEiOSSupportCore/DVTiPhoneSimulator.m:615
Details:  Unexpectedly found two active proxied devices for companion dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:E32D007F-6826-4EE3-BD9A-DB9B8CE1796F: dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:F8874B60-9233-423E-9C9C-2DC3E3A3509D and dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:F8874B60-9233-423E-9C9C-2DC3E3A3509D**

I have removed Xcode from my computer and reinstalled it from scratch. But to no avail. There is something hiding in the cache that I should get rid of, but I have no clue what it could be.

Comment: I don't know for sure what it's complaining about but you might try looking in '~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` for those names.

Comment: I deleted everything related to xcode, re-installed and now it works. thank you,